# Writing editor content to a file

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I have a project I'm working on where I need to write the content of the post editor to a physical file on the web server when a post is saved or updated. I'll be parsing and manipulating the content before writing, but I'm having trouble just getting it loaded into a variable. Is there a different way I should be going about this and/or is there something I'm missing? Currently the file it writes is blank, if I throw a simple string into $content it's written to the file leading me to believe get_the_content() isn't working. Any ideas?

```
function pht_write_file() {  
$file = WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/myplugin/test.xml"; 
$content = get_the_content();
file_put_contents($file, $content);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'pht_write_file');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hook `save_post` instead of `publish_post`. `publish_post` only runs when a post is initially published and won't catch subsequent saves.

Additionally, the `publish_post` hook passes parameters to your function and those should be used to retrieve info about the post being published rather `get_the_content()`, which only works when you're inside the loop.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
function pht_write_file($post_id){
    if(get_post_status($post_id) !== 'publish') return; //only run if post is published
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $file = WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/myplugin/test.xml"; 
}
add_action('save_post', 'pht_write_file');
```

This function will also correctly hook to `publish_post` in the case where you did mean for the text to only be saved on publish instead of on save.